# how to increase/decrease the value on an element in a neo4j cypher list

Tags: neo4j, cypher, apoc

I have a cypher list say slots=[1,2,3,4]. How can I do something like this:
slots[0] +=1 so that slot[0] would now be increased by 1. I couldn't find a SET command or an APOC that would allow this.

This is my expected result:

```
[2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple list comprehension will do.  Using index from 0 to 3, add one to the item if it is first element (index 0), else copy the value of the item in the list

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] as slots
RETURN [ i IN range(0, size(slots)-1) |
    case when i=0 then slots[i]+1 else slots[i] end ]
```

Result:

```
[2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: right .. overlooked that simpler (and therfore better) solution ;)

Comment: we are agile and iterative so we keep on improving things. :D

Comment: Thanks you guys for both responses. However neither addresses my question. I am not trying to increase/decrease all the values in the list ...just one. If I RETURN myList[0] the result is 1. I want to change that to something like SET myList[0] = 1. Then RETURN myList[0] result would be 1.

Comment: Ok...you maybe on the right track but still not correct. When you do RETURN slots[0]+1 you will get 2 but the value of slots[0] is not changed so RETURN slots[0]+1 is not an answer. I need to change the value of the property with a SET command.

Comment: Ok....I was able to make it work with the SET command ...SET n.available_slots = [ i IN range(0, size(n.available_slots)-1) |
    case when i=3 then n.available_slots[i]-1 else n.available_slots[i] end ]   RETURN n.available_slots .....I don't quite understand it but the property is changed like I wanted.

Comment: Glad that it works well for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REDUCE() for this

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] as myList
RETURN REDUCE(list=[], i IN myList | list + [i + 1])
```